# Who is in the cafe scene in Dark Knight Rises

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises, plot-explanation

In the final scene of The Dark Knight Rises we see Bruce sitting at the table with a brunette.

[image: Scene in cafe]

Is this woman Selina Kyle or is it someone he's met in his new life?

Comment: It looks like _Michelle Monaghan_ a bit. But it seems stupid for such a small time, she would be called.

Comment: It is definitely [Anne Hathaway](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004266/) in her role as [Selina Kyle](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0238305/).

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/11704/49

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is definitely *Selina Kyle*, never thought it could be someone else (and have *never* heard anybody *not* referring to her being *Selina Kyle*). Yet that particular screenshot is indeed a bit vague, but together with the fact that due to the story's development she is most probable to be *Selina Kyle* it still bears enough resemblence to *Anne Hathaway* to be quite sure.

And in fact [the movie's script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Dark-Knight-Rises,-The.html) agrees with me:

> EXT. CAFÉ, FLORENCE - DAY
>
> Alfred folds his paper. Pulls out his money, then stops,
>   seeing...across the tables, a familiar couple... Bruce smiles at
>   Alfred, who nods. Bruce turns back to the pretty brunette in pearls.
>   Selina. Alfred pays his bill, content.

Comment: Note also that she appears to be wearing the necklace she steals early in the movie - I don't believe Bruce ever got it back.

Comment: @AdamV Hah, right, might be possible, never noticed that. Yet I think he got them back at the ball (when she in turn took his car) but maybe gave them back to her later on, since *"they really look much better on her"*.

Comment: sounds familiar, but I can't remember for sure. I'll re-watch the movie to confirm.