# Bruce Wayne's death in The Dark Knight Rises

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

People witnessed the death of Batman. They do not know that Bruce Wayne was Batman. However, the death of Bruce Wayne himself would be highly publicized, due to his stature. It would be known to the entire world.

How could he fake a death and then be present at a cafe in Italy without publicity or consequences?

This is what Alfred dreamed of, so there is a possibility that this is Alfred's imagination but the closing scenes with Fox and Gordon suggest that Bruce Wayne is alive.

Comment: Related [Evidence for and against the ending of Dark Knight Rises](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/evidence-for-and-against-the-ending-of-dark-knight-rises)

Comment: Isn't it ironic that 'Joker' is asking about Ba(shh..) Bruce Wayne's death o.0

Comment: Only if your Alanis Morissette.

Comment: He's very sneaky, he is Batman after all...

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson. This question isn't a duplicate. It's not asking about a link between Bruce Wayne and Batman being deduced from the supposed deaths. It's asking how can there not be consequences of just appearing in public after a purported death.

Answer (score 3):

When Gotham was placed under siege by Bane's men, all the rich and wealthy were dragged out, placed in a kangaroo court, and summarily executed or 'banished', which in itself is execution.

It will have been assumed Bruce Wayne was amongst the number of wealthy citizens who were murdered. As you say, given his stature, it would have raised *more* questions if he'd actually survived this process.

Comment: Ok but him showing up in public sometime after the events, how would something like that be received, if it was documented and publicized that he was dead?

Comment: Not only has Bruce Wayne been supposedly dead for some time by this point, prior to this death he had been living in isolation. There are probably very few people who would recognise him, coupled with the fact that no-one is looking for him, added to the fact he's on another continent. Even if someone knew of Bruce Wayne, they'd almost certainly assume it was someone who 'looked a bit like Bruce Wayne', rather than the man himself, back from the dead.